# Выборка товаров из mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Как реализовать вот такую выборку?
В базе данных есть несколько товаров с одинаковым штрих-кодом, отличие только в цвете. Мне нужно получить кол-во всех этих товаров у которых одинаковый штрих код, но при этом получить один из всех товаров вместе с общим количеством

Запрос:

```
`SELECT  SUM(avaliableCount) as avaliableCount FROM `products2 WHERE barcode = '1488'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос:

```
 SELECT * FROM `products2` WHERE barcode = '1488';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы при выборке avaliableCount был сумой всех товаров

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)